# Are any biology research journals free to publish in?

Tags: research-process

The research journals Ive published in require significant financial cost to publish. On top of that many require a membership to the society the journal is associated with, in addition to publication fees. I was wondering if anyone is familiar with any journals (reputable hopefully) that do not require fees like this to publish a research article?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on-topic here. Perhaps Academia SE would be a better fit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many biology journals are free to publish in. As a rule of thumb:

- Most journals from for-profit publishers such as Elsevier, Wiley, etc. charge nothing to the author (but of course bill the libraries handsomely).
- Many but by no means all society journals charge page charges even if they are not open access.
- Most but not all open access journals charge substantial publication fees. You could try [this website](http://www.eigenfactor.org/openaccess/) to search for open access journals that do not charge publication fees.